# How do I implement my own printf in c

Tags: c, printf

I am recreating the C function `printf`, after the `%` the function goes to the if statement bellow, if I do not know the data type for the second argument how do I use `va_arg()` to access the arguments passed to my `printf` to print?

```
if (str[a] == 'c' || str[a] == 'd' || str[a] == 's')
    print_char(str[a], va_arg(arg, ));
```

This is my original code, but it is too long, I have to make it 25 line at most. that is why I want to pass the character after `%` to a function that will then print the value stored in the argument

```
void ft_printf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    char *s;
    unsigned int i;
    char *str;
    int a;

    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, fmt);
    str = fmt;
    a = 0;
    while (str[a])
    {
        while (str[a] == ' ' || str[a] == '\t')
            a++;

        while (str[a] != '%')
        {
            ft_putchar(str[a]);
            a++;
        }
        a++;
        if (str[a] == 'c')
        {
            i = va_arg(arg, int);
            ft_putchar(i);
        }
        else if (str[a] == 'd')
        {
            i = va_arg(arg, int);
            ft_putchar(i);
        }
        else if (str[a] == 's')
        {
            s = va_arg(arg, char *);
            ft_putstr(s);
        }
        a++;
    }
    va_end(arg);
}
```

Comment: You can tell the data type from the format string. `%f` for example is a float, so when you do that, you simply get a float the `va_list`.

Comment: I have to pass both the character after the % , and the value stored in that character to  function, if i use the method demonstrated in this link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735236/how-to-write-my-own-printf-in-c . the code becomes to long, that is why i want to pass is to a function

Comment: It's impossible to write a printf function in under 25 lines. `printf()` has many possible format markers, you just need to visit `man -s3 printf`.

Comment: You can use `vprintf()` to implement a printf, but that is probably not allowed

Comment: If its only decreased line count, you're after you can change your if else change to a switch statement. Also, since your code to handle 'c' and 'd' is the same you cand test for them in one if statement

Comment: `else if (str[a] == 'd')
        {
            i = va_arg(arg, int);
            ft_putchar(i);
        }` does not properly print `i` as a decimal text.

Comment: `while(str[a] != '%')
        {
            ft_putchar(str[a]);
            a++;
        }` likely runs past the end of the format.

Comment: Possible hints at http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html

Comment: I'd suggest that P J Plauger
[The Standard C Library](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131315099) 1992 still makes good reading — and has a good C90 `printf()` implementation.  There were some enhancements required by C99 (notably `long long` support), but the core is more than adequate for your current purposes.  I doubt if all the functions are 25 lines long or shorter (many are; some are probably longer).

Answer (score 3):

First, you should implement `printf` as a call to `vfprintf()`, passing the `va_list` by value.

In your `ft_vfprintf()` function, you could pass the `va_list` by value to a function specific for each format, via an array of function pointers, but they would not update the `va_list` in the caller correctly and you cannot portably pass a pointer to the `va_list` as this type might be defined as an array. Yet these functions can take the `va_list` along with other information to continue the parsing recursively.

This approach is called *compiling with continuations*, where each function calls the next one and returns its result. If the compiler can handle these tail calls efficiently, the stack depth for long format strings with many arguments might stay small, otherwise it is still within reasonable limits: two recursive call for each conversion specification.

I doubt this is what the folks at *42* or *Epitech* expect from you, but it is a way to implement `printf` with small functions. Note however that a full implementation is *non-trivial* as the format specifications may also contain flags, modifiers and width and precision arguments, but it might still be feasible with extra state information.

Here is a simplistic example:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_putchar(int c) {
    char a[1];
    a[0] = (char)c;
    return write(0, a, 1);
}

static int ft_printf_aux(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len);

static int ft_print_c(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    int c = va_arg(ap, int);
    ft_putchar(c);
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len + 1);
}

static int ft_putnum(unsigned long long n, unsigned int base, const char *digits) {
    int res = 1;
    if (n >= base)
        res += ft_putnum(n / base, base, digits);
    ft_putchar(digits[n % base]);
    return res;
}

static int ft_print_d(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    int n = va_arg(ap, int);
    unsigned long long u;
    if (n < 0) {
        ft_putchar('-');
        len++;
        u = -(unsigned)n;
    } else {
        u = n;
    }
    len += ft_putnum(u, 10, "0123456789");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_o(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 8, "01234567");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_u(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 10, "0123456789");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_x(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 16, "0123456789abcdef");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_X(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    unsigned int n = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
    len += ft_putnum(n, 16, "0123456789ABCDEF");
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

static int ft_print_s(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    const char *s = va_arg(ap, const char *);
    if (s == NULL) {
        s = "(null)";
    }
    while (*s) {
        ft_putchar(*s++);
        len++;
    }
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, len);
}

typedef int (*ft_print_dispatch_f)(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len);

static ft_print_dispatch_f const ft_print_dispatch[256] = {
    ['c'] = ft_print_c,
    ['d'] = ft_print_d,
    ['i'] = ft_print_d,
    ['o'] = ft_print_o,
    ['u'] = ft_print_u,
    ['x'] = ft_print_x,
    ['X'] = ft_print_X,
    ['s'] = ft_print_s,
};

static int ft_printf_aux(const char *fmt, va_list ap, int len) {
    int c;

    while (*fmt) {
        c = (unsigned char)*fmt++;
        if (c != '%') {
            ft_putchar(c);
            len++;
        } else {
            c = (unsigned char)*fmt++;
            if (ft_print_dispatch[c] == NULL) {
                if (c == '\0')
                    break;
                ft_putchar(c);
                len++;
            } else {
                return ft_print_dispatch[c](fmt, ap, len);
            }
        }
    }
    return len;
}

int ft_vprintf(const char *fmt, va_list ap) {
    return ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, 0);
}

int ft_printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int n;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = ft_printf_aux(fmt, ap, 0);
    va_end(ap);
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    ft_printf("Hello word\n");
    ft_printf("%cello %s\n", 'H', "word");
    ft_printf("%d == 0%o == 0x%x == 0x%X\n", 1, 1, 1, 1);
    ft_printf("%d == 0%o == 0x%x == 0x%X\n", 123, 123, 123, 123);
    ft_printf("%d == 0%o == 0x%x == 0x%X\n", 0xdead, 0xdead, 0xdead, 0xdead);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JohnsonMizzyDubula: did this answer help you?