# Redirect printf to fopencookie

Tags: c, printf, raspbian, glibc, stdio

On Linux (Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi) I would like to make it so that anything my C application prints using `printf` is sent back to me in a callback.

(No, I'm not talking about shell redirection with `> some_file.txt`.  I'm talking about a C program making the decision *by itself* to send `stdout` (and therefore `printf`) to a callback within that same program.)

(Yes, I really do want to do this.  I'm making a full-screen program using OpenGL and want to present any `printf`'d text to the user within that program, using my own rendering code.  Replacing all `printf` calls with something else is not feasible.)

I feel like this should be easy.  There are variations of this question on StackOverflow already, but none that I could find are exactly the same.

I can use `fopencookie` to get a `FILE*` that ends up calling my callback.  So far, so good.  The challenge is to get `stdout` and `printf` to go there.

I *can't* use `freopen` because it takes a string path.  The `FILE*` I want to redirect to is not a file on the filesystem but rather just exists at runtime.

I *can't* use `dup2` because the `FILE*` from `fopencookie` does not have a file descriptor (`fileno` returns -1).

The [glibc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html) suggests that I can simply reassign `stdout` to my new `FILE*`: *"stdin, stdout, and stderr are normal variables which you can set just like any others."*.   This **does almost work**.  Anything printed with `fprintf (stdout, "whatever")` *does* go to my callback, and so does any `printf` that has any format specifiers.  However, any call to `printf` with a string with  no format specifiers at all still goes to the "original" stdout.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

PS: I don't care about portability.  This will only ever run on my current environment.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE                                                         
#include <stdio.h>                                                          
#include <unistd.h>                                                         
#include <assert.h>                                                         
#include <stdarg.h>                                                         
#include <alloca.h>                                                         
#include <string.h>                                                         


static ssize_t my_write_func (void * cookie, const char * buf, size_t size) 
{                                                                           
    fprintf (stderr, "my_write_func received %d bytes\n", size);            
    char * copy = (char*) alloca (size + 1);                                
    assert (copy);                                                          
    copy[size] = 0;                                                         
    strncpy (copy, buf, size);                                              
    fprintf (stderr, "Text is: \"%s\"\n", copy);                            
    fflush (stderr);                                                        
    return size;                                                            
}                                                                           


static FILE * create_opencookie ()                                          
{                                                                           
    cookie_io_functions_t funcs;                                            
    memset (&funcs, 0, sizeof (funcs));                                     
    funcs.write = my_write_func;                                            
    FILE * f = fopencookie (NULL, "w", funcs);                              
    assert (f);                                                             
    return f;                                                               
}                                                                           


int main (int argc, char ** argv)                                           
{                                                                           
    FILE * f = create_opencookie ();                                        
    fclose (stdout);                                                        
    stdout = f;                                                             

    // These two DO go to my callback:                                                                        
    fprintf (stdout, "This is a long string, fprintf'd to stdout\n");                           
    printf ("Hello world, this is a printf with a digit: %d\n", 123);

    // This does not go to my callback.
    // If I omit the fclose above then it gets printed to the console.
    printf ("Hello world, this is plain printf.\n");           
    fflush (NULL);                                                          
    return 0;                                                               
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the glibc printf extension.  Have you considered just using `#define printf cookie_printf` or something to that effect.  It's pretty easy to write your own function that has the same signature as `printf` that then calls `vfprintf`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737675/1028434

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in GLIBC.

The reason that `printf("simple string")` works differently from `printf("foo %d", 123)` is that GCC transforms the former into a `puts`, with the notion that they are equivalent.

As far as I can tell, they *should* be equivalent. [This man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html) states that `puts` outputs to `stdout`, just like `printf` does.

However, in GLIBC `printf` outputs to `stdout` [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/printf.c;h=ea41dd557c9c04d16014f69ae709bbc7d5ac7581;hb=HEAD#l33), but `puts` outputs to `_IO_stdout` [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/ioputs.c;h=c9967c3883b303979c9a184a1e928345d6dcf3c5;hb=HEAD#l40), and these are *not* equivalent. [This has already been reported as a glibc bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761300) [(upstream bug).](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24051)

To work around this bug, you could build with `-fno-builtin-printf` flag. That prevents GCC from transforming `printf` into `puts`, and on my system produces:

```
$ ./a.out
my_write_func received 126 bytes
Text is: "This is a long string, fprintf'd to stdout
Hello world, this is a printf with a digit: 123
Hello world, this is plain printf.
"
```

This workaround is of course incomplete: if you call `puts` directly, or link in object files that call `printf("simple string")` and were *not* compiled with `-fno-builtin-printf` (perhaps from 3rd-party library), then you'll still have a problem.

Unfortunately you can't assign to `_IO_stdout` (which is a macro). The only other thing you could do (that I can think of) is link in your own `puts`, which just returns `printf("%s", arg)`. That should work if you are linking against `libc.so.6`, but may cause trouble if you link against `libc.a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to a pipe instead and process the written data in a separate thread.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// this is the original program which you can't change
void print(void) {
    printf("Hello, %d\n", 123);
    puts("world");
    printf("xyz");
}

int p[2];

void *render(void *arg) {
    int nread;
    char buf[1];
    while((nread = read(p[0], buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
        // process the written data, in this case - make it uppercase and write to stderr
        for(int i = 0; i < nread; i++)
            buf[i] = toupper(buf[i]);
        write(2, buf, nread);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    pipe(p);
    dup2(p[1], 1);
    close(p[1]);
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, render, NULL);
    print();
    close(1);
    pthread_join(t, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On debian stretch putting:

```
setvbuf (f, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);  // line buffered
```

after the create_opencookie call worked.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please use code tags to make your answer more readable.